# Using SignalR in a Website Project

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I'm trying a very simple demo of SignalR but getting the infamous "undefined" error on the following line in my javascript:

```
var myHub = $.connection.myHub;
```

MyHub.cs is as follows:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    ...
}
```

Most of the examples I've seen so far are MVC or web application projects. With those, MyHub.cs would be placed in the App_Code folder. However, our project is a website project and we can't change it to a web application.

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that I missed the following in web.config:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

And yes, you can absolutely use SignalR in a website project.

Comment: Well I found out that I need to place it inside <system.webServer>, but the same error shows up.