# Implementing The SingalR Sample Into An ASP.Net WEB SITE APPLICATION -- Error In JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

I am trying to implement the SignalR into my ASP.Net "WEB SITE PROJECT".  (This is an existing application and it is a Web Site Project, and can not be changed over to be a Web Application.)

I get the following error when I try to run the SignalR Sample code.  (This is the basic stock ticker sample.  Just wanting to verify I have everything setup correctly before I start implementing this into my existing code.)

### Here is the error I get

```
Unhandled exception at line 71, column 5 in http://localhost:49218/SchoolFinancial/SignalR.Sample/SignalR.StockTicker.js

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'client': object is null or undefined
```

### Here is the javascript that the error is thrown with

```
// Add client-side hub methods that the server will call
$.extend(ticker.client, {
    updateStockPrice: function (stock) {
        var displayStock = formatStock(stock),
            $row = $(rowTemplate.supplant(displayStock)),
            $li = $(liTemplate.supplant(displayStock)),
            bg = stock.LastChange === 0
                ? '255,216,0' // yellow
                : stock.LastChange > 0
                    ? '154,240,117' // green
                    : '255,148,148'; // red

        $stockTableBody.find('tr[data-symbol=' + stock.Symbol + ']')
            .replaceWith($row);
        $stockTickerUl.find('li[data-symbol=' + stock.Symbol + ']')
            .replaceWith($li);

        $row.flash(bg, 1000);
        $li.flash(bg, 1000);
    },

    marketOpened: function () {
        $("#open").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#close").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#reset").prop("disabled", true);
        scrollTicker();
    },

    marketClosed: function () {
        $("#open").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#close").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#reset").prop("disabled", false);
        stopTicker();
    },

    marketReset: function () {
        return init();
    }
});
```

### Here is the Web.Config setting change that is to allow SignalR work with a Web Site project

(This is inside of the following section of the Web.Config   )

```
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  </modules>
```

I am NEW to using SignalR and from what I have found from a previous post, this should solve my issue if I can get it working.

So, if anyone has any experience with using the SignalR in a Web Site Project in ASP.Net I would greatly appreciate any suggestions / recommendations.

Not sure if it matters or not, but I am using Visual Studio 2012 (ASP.Net / C#) and my web site is on the .Net Framework 4.5 version.

Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: I want to add that I am able to get this to run if I create an ASP.Net Web Application, rather than an ASP.Net Web Site project.  I pulled the latest version of the code from NuGet so I know I have the latest code.  From what I have found in researching this, the web.config setting that I added for the modules is what is needed for this to run in an ASP.Net Web Site project.  However, I continue to get the error and can not find any other recommendations / solutions.  Also, converting my project over to an ASP.Net Web Application is not an option as it is an existing project.  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error probably because of the any of the following reasons:-

1) yourbaseurl/signalr/hubs is giving 404. You can verify that in the chrome console after the page is loaded. If you are getting this error you need to make sure that the Hub routes are mapped. using

```
RouteTable.Route.MapHubs()
```

either in your global.asax application start or using some startup injector like WebActivatorEx.

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    }
```

2) All the SIgnalr related dlls are of compatible versions. This wont be an issue if you have installed with library package manager console.

3) if above steps is not the issue then the issue is that the client proxies are not getting generated properly. This means if you hit yourbaseurl/signalr/hubs you should be able to see the hub registered with the name same as the c# hub class name in camel case and

```
proxies.stockTicker.client
```

initialized and

```
proxies.stockTicker.server
```

defined with the function names same as that declared in the c# HubProxy. And all of these present under the following prototype decalration .

```
 $.hubConnection.prototype.createHubProxies
```

4) If you are not able to get the proxy generated as per step 3 try placing the class files in the SignalR.StockTicker in to the AppCode.

Note:- I just tried and got the sample working in Asp.Net 4.5 website.

All the Best!!

Comment: Thanks for your time...  I will update later today as to which one of the items it ended up being..   Thanks..!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks...  Adding RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs() to my Application_Start in the Global.asax.cs file fixed this for me..   THANK YOU for all your help!!!!!

Comment: One final question...   When I tie the signalR to my link button it works fine as long as it is outside of an update pane.  However, when I place my linkbutton inside of an update panel, it works fine the first time, however, every time after that it does not work until I redirect back to the page and try again.  Then again it works for the first time only.  Any ideas how I can get this to reinitialize each time the page postback