# Signalr TypeError: chat is undefined issue

Tags: asp.net, signalr

i am trying to learning this signalr library. so i just install signalr related all dependency from Nuget.

when i run my code then i am getting error called **TypeError: chat is undefined**
this all js library are included.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.1.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'  type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

when this line execute then i am getting the above error

```
chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message)
```

i follow the full instruction from this url to create a sample project. the url is
**http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr**

can anyone tell me how to fix this error. thanks

Comment: i definitely doing some mistake and that is why chat is undefined issue occur. i am running my asp.net webform apps from VS2010 IDE. am i doing anything wrong. please guide me how solve this error. thanks

Comment: Try updating the version of jQuery. Also what does your Hub class look like?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485804/implementing-the-singalr-sample-into-an-asp-net-web-site-application-error-in/15490677#15490677 as see if this helps.

Comment: @PSCoder your link help me. thanks but still i have one issue that when i am trying to call client side method from server side then nothing happen. can u tell me the reason.

Comment: Do you still have this issue? Do you see any errors logged in the console? DO you see the connection in chrome console?

Comment: sorry everything fix up thanks.

Comment: can u guide me how to broad cast message from web app to win app using signalr. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your server side Application Start make sure that you are calling RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs().  #7 in the tutorial

Comment: thanks for answer. @PSCoder link help me. but still i have one issue that when i am trying to call client side method from server side then nothing happen. can u tell me the reason. where i need to lookup & what i need to fix