# 404:signalr/hubs for signalR chat application

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying to create a chat application using signalR using VS2012 web in a website. 
But its showing me error like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   
http://localhost:50780/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/signalr/hubs
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
```

I have added  `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` to Global.asax
But why should its showing me this error when its opening for other's system.

Comment: See if this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485804/implementing-the-singalr-sample-into-an-asp-net-web-site-application-error-in/15490677#comment21945120_15490677

Answer (score 0):

On the page where you're including signalr/hubs:

Change your script tag to look like this:

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

@drch's answer is also correct (if you're making that mistake) but the more common issue I see is people just doing "signalr/hubs" in their script tag and then the hubs url is then incorrect (in some circumstances).

Ultimately the hubs url resides off of the SignalR endpoint so doing a "~/signalr/hubs" makes the path app relative which should ensure that it retrieves the hubs.js from the correct url.

Comment: When i use <script src="signalr/hubs"></script> for a project, then its working fine. But its showing me error if i use for a website. I have tried your solution also, not working

Comment: When you host your page on your site you need to find out where your SignalR endpoint is.  Point the signalr/hubs url to that location

Comment: I am newbie to signalR. So can you please tell me how to find signalr/hubs url?

Answer (score 0):

I know, that I'm late, but for smbd who will finding answers:
I've resolved the problem by registrate .Net frame work to IIS.
Do next steps into console (Win+R):

```
cd %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
aspnet_regiis.exe –i
```

[Source](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-deploying-to-iis-as-a-test-environment-5-of-12)